# Exibir data e hora em PHP

Tags: php, windows

Estou tentando exibir a hora exata com PHP no seguinte formato.

> Data: AAAA-MM-DD
>
> Hora: 00:00:00:000

```
  <?php 
       setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
       date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
       echo strftime( '%Y-%m-%e %T', strtotime('today')); 
?>
```

Com o código atual ele segundo a minha pesquisa iria exibir isto por exemplo, 2015-01-26 00:00:00

Estou usando windows7 x64 e PHP Versão 5.5.8 e a página não exibe nada, nem erros.

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: @JorgeB. a pagina gerada não exibe nada, nem erros

Comment: Em sistema operaciona está usando?

Comment: Já foste ver o log? Tens os warnings e erros a aparecer na página? Ou só no log?

Comment: @rray windows 7 x64

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema http://ideone.com/eG9gmq

Comment: Aqui funciona direito também: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/w1f0-b7ij

Comment: o `%e` não é suportado pelo windows, [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) troque por `%d`.

Comment: @rray o %d também não é suportado? estou tentando usa-lo mas nada acontece!

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui, so funcionou com o `%d` e removendo também o `%T`.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a versão do php tbm.

Comment: @rray a data está certo, vou tentar resolver a hora, obg

Comment: Quem vai responder?

Comment: @bigown desculpe não entendi!

Comment: O @rray entendeu o recado.

Comment: Se não precisar formatar a data localizada(traduzida) a função `date()` parace mais simples.

Comment: eu sempre pensei que a função `date()` pegava o horário e data local

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é a função [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), que não faz a conversão do timestamp corretamente no windows, alguns argumentos como a documentação alerta não são suportados:

```
%e, %T, %R, %D
```

Para que seu código funcione troque `%e` e `%T` por,

`%d` para o dia com dois digitos 01-31.

`%H` para exibir a hora no formato 00-23

`%M` para minutos no formato 00-59

`%S` Para segundo no formato 00-59

O código deve ficar dessa forma:

```
echo strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime('today') );
```

[Lista com os argumentos suportados no windows - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Experimente:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está no `strtotime` em que você colocou `today`, traduzindo, `hoje`. Tente colocar `now` (`agora`).

```
echo strftime( '%Y-%m-%e %T', strtotime('now'));
```

Comment: já havia tentado, continuava da mesma forma os problemas eram mesmo relacionados ao strftime.

Answer (score 1):

**Para exibir:** Data: AAAA-MM-DD e com a hora atual:

```
<?php

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u');
    echo $date;


?>
```