# Formatar data vindo de variável com php

Tags: php, data

Possuo a variável abaixo e quero formatar para o padrão brasileiro (20/01/2015) usando PHP.

```
$data = Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2016
```

Comment: `Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2016` é a saída da variável. Daí precisa ver como está declarada. No caso acho que tá usando [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Pra exibir por exemplo a data do dia de hoje no formato que vc quer usando date, é fazer simplesmente `$data = date("d-m-Y");`

Comment: Na verdade ela sai como um array:
[x-inquiry-arrival] => Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2016

Comment: Posta a declaração da variável...

Comment: O php esta lendo essa variavel como um texto e não como data, como transformo isso em data, dai depois eu faço a formatação.

Comment: Acho que [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29694/converter-uma-data-para-o-nome-do-dia-da-semana) pode te ajudar... Em tem [esta outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48309/exibir-data-e-hora-em-php?rq=1) também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converta essa data por para timestamp com `strtotime()` e depois pegue no formato desejado com `date()`

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2016'));
```

[Exemplo - 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/K5AgC)